# Storybook JS Interaction Testing with Enzyme - State Changes being Overidden

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, storybook

I am using storybook to visualize changes to React components after simulating user interaction with enzyme. As a small example, I want a story displaying a component after one of its button has been clicked.

The issue I'm having is the component's constructor gets called twice: once when the component is mounted by enzyme and then after when storybook displays the component. This puts the component back to its default state so any changes following the simulated user interactions are lost.

Here's some code showing the issue. After the story loads, the button component is in the "unclicked" state, even though a click was simulated with enzyme:

```
import React from 'react';

class SampleComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('constructor');

        this.state = {isClicked: false};
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(){
        console.log('onClick');
        this.setState({isClicked: true});
    }

    render(){
        const text = (this.state.isClicked)? 'Clicked!' : 'Not Clicked';
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='button' value='Click' onClick={this.onClick} />
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SampleComponent;
```

The story file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { specs, describe, it } from 'storybook-addon-specifications';
import SampleComponent from '../src/SampleComponent';

storiesOf('SampleComponent', module)
    .add('clicked', () => {

        const comp = <SampleComponent/>;
        specs(() => describe('clicked', function () {
            it('Should display clicked state message', function () {
                const output = mount(comp);
                output.find('input').simulate('click');
            });
        }));

        return comp;
    });
```

The output to console would be:

```
constructor
onClick
constructor
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to get back the underlying component instance. This will do what you want:

```
storiesOf('SampleComponent', module)
  .add('clicked', () => {
    let output;

    specs(() => describe('clicked', function () {
      it('Should display clicked state message', function () {
        output = mount(<SampleComponent />);
        output.find('input').simulate('click');
      });
    }));

    const Inst = () => output.instance();
    return <Inst />
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to use storyboard and simulate('click') and ran into similar problems. I would never see the after clicked state in the storybook pane.  I figured out that mount(comp) is rendering the comp into a separate DOM - not the one that storybook is using. When you return comp, comp is rendered in the browser and that's what you see.  It could be a configuration issue I haven't figured out.  I am using the webpack configuration described at https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-addon-specifications#using-enzyme

This does what you are trying to do, through without using enzyme:

```
storiesOf('SampleComponent', module)
.add('clicked', () => {
    const comp = <SampleComponent/>;
    setTimeout(()=>{        // let Storybook render comp and then come back
        let input=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        input.click(); // browser simulated click
        specs(() => describe('clicked', function () {
            it('Should display clicked state message', function () {
                let p=document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
                return (p.innerText==='Clicked!')
            });
        }))
    },1000) // the timeout could be 0 for faster test execution, but 1000 millisecond gives you a change to see that the click takes place
    return comp;
});
```